# MongoDB: replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed "server is not running with --replSet"

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, replicaset

I try to setup a Replica Set on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.
First error I run into when trying

```
$ sudo mongod --port 27017 --replSet rs0:

replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
```

I read that `> rs.initiate()` solves that issue, so I do

```
$ sudo service mongod start
$ mongo
rs.initiate()
```

which throws:

```
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "server is not running with --replSet" }
```

So if I can't start mongod with `--replSet` how can I solve the error within `rs.initiate()` which I need to solve the first error?
It's like a vicious circle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved the problem by using a second command shell:

console1:

```
$ sudo mongod --port 27017 --replSet rs0
```

console2:

```
$ mongo
  > rs.initiate()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set this replSet in **/etc/mongodb.conf** file,

```
# Replication
replication:
   replSetName: rs0

#fork
processManagement:
   fork: true
```

Fork for running in background.

Now start mongod,

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

To check the process status,

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

Refer : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/